# How vitals are related to encounter in c-cda clinical document?

Tags: xml, ccd, hl7-cda, hl7-v3, hl7-v2

i have some questions about encounters in CCDA clinical document.

1) why componentOf tag is used in header if there is encounter template in body of CCDA XML document.

2) Vital is always against some encounter. How can i relate them? how do i know which vital is against which encounter?
how is it possible that we have one encounter and two vital entries?
I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Ok - first, please find someone with clinical experience. It is very possible to have multiple vital entries for one encounter depending upon several factors, such as the condition of the patient, if a med was given, a before and after reading - any of these reasons or more.

Also, the dates are right at the head the component in the first table - that's the encounter date. Once again, I would definitely suggest finding someone who can help navigate the complex world of medical care, because it certainly becomes far more complicated beyond vitals.

Comment: Vital(s) is(are) captured as part of a visit (encounter) hence they are related and should be captured in db / cda.